# Change shortcut in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I 'd like to do a presentation with a [wireless USB remote control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FPGP4U). At one moment, I need to go to the previous **animation phase** – which would be the shortcut `Shift–Left Arrow` or `[` (left bracket).

However, with my presenter it is only possible to go the previous **slide** — which would be the shortcut `P`, `Delete`, `Page Up`, `Left Arrow`, `Up Arrow`, or `Shift–Up Arrow`.

I do not want to use a keyboard since I want to speak freely in my presentation.

So the questions are: Is this a problem of my remote control? In other words: Are there remote controls that as well have a "previous animation phase" button? Do I need to somehow trick the system to make it work?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: do you have a remote which simulates key presses on a keyboard? Which model?

Comment: No I have a normal [remote presenter](http://www.amazon.de/ACCO-Brands-Benelux-BV-33374/dp/B000FPGP4U/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1366621874&sr=8-2&keywords=presenter). I think they all work the same!? All of them have just one forward and one backward key. But backwards is in fact 'go back to the beginning of the slide' and not the previous animation phase.

Comment: I have the same presenter! It never occurred to me you could go back one **animation phase**! Thanks for that. Regarding your question: Generally it **is** possible to re-configure keyboard commands for any item that is in menus. Seems there is no menu command for `Shift-Back Arrow` -- or is it? Have to think about that...

Comment: I thought of that too, but since there is no item in the menu, the system preferences is a blind alley I guess...

Comment: If you activate [Caps Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_lock) on your keyboard during your presentation, it might work with the presenter. Can’t test b/c my CL key is broken :)

Comment: Oh man, of course that should work. I am embarassed. I would vote this question down if I could :)

Comment: Ok actually, it does not work. The 'left' key of presenters seem to be related to the 'up' key of the keyboard! This means, even with cap locks, you cannot go back one animation phase... So still there is no solution! And: I don't feel embarrassed any more!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in Mavericks pretty easily (I just did).

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, select "App Shortcuts" and click the + button. You'll be asked to select the app you want to create a shortcut for (Keynote, in my case), the exact text of the menu item you want to create a new shortcut for ("Play Slideshow" in my case), and the keyboard shortcut you want to assign (Shift-F5 in my case, which is what the Logitech R400 uses for "start slideshow").

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your remote simply simulates a certain key press. You will need to remap your `page up` (⇞) key to `shift left` temporarily (as long as you don’t need "page up" functionality — typically during your presentation). My recommendation is [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), more info [here](http://www.hackcollege.com/blog/2012/04/04/app-of-the-week-%E2%80%93-remap-your-mac%E2%80%99s-keyboard-with-keyremap4macbook.html). The app has a passthru option which you should activate if you do not want any key remapped outside of presentations. Hope this helps!

Comment: And it is not possible to remap the presenters keys? I sent an email to the manufacturer but no reply yet. Any experience if this could be done?

Comment: I am curious how your research will turn out. However, my final recommendation is: any software solution will be easier to do than hardware modification. Good luck!