# Remove Keynote keyboard shortcut

Tags: keynote

Is it possible to remove or change a keyboard shortcut in Keynote? I found [this question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89426/change-shortcut-in-keynote) about creating a new one, but it doesn't address removing a standard one. Specifically, I find it really annoying that the Play/Pause button on my keyboard starts a presentation when I press it expecting my music to Play/Pause.

I'm on macOS 10.13.3, Keynote v7.3.1

Comment: You would probably need to install a 3rd party application like Karibiner or Better Touch Tool.  Are you open to that?  Also, can you [edit] your question to include your OS & Keynote versions?

Comment: I'm open to that. Karabiner looks pretty straightforward. Thanks for the reference